# Managing label spacing/density in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, labeling

How to manage space in between labels (or density)?

I would like to have less labels in order to have more space in between.
The label order is not important.

---

I would like to precise is just for city name labels, not street name or like.

A picture is better than a long explanation :

[image]

---

THE RESULT

[image]

Comment: Just to clarify: You want to label cities. Not all of them but some random ones? Isn't there some classification in your data which can be used to label only the bigger/important ones?

Comment: Classification is OSM one (town, city, village). So around PARIS many are city. Label tool show them all and avoid the overlap of course. But for my need I need more 'air' in between labels. This mean less label with more space around. If they where an option, it would be "Blank space Y/X around the label"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use an expression like

```
'\n\n\n' || name || '                    '
```

It adds some empty lines in the beginning and extra spaces to the end which are respected by the QGIS labeling engine when it computes collisions.

[image]

It's a horrible hack but i works kind of

[image]

Comment: Can you be more precise  how to use this hack. I'm not so good in QGIS expression...

Comment: SUPER ! Can you explain what is does in human language ?

Comment: I understand the hack. But as you see I use also label background, and this affect the background :-(

Comment: I think there is currently no way for you to get everything you want. Consider sponsoring a developer to add the necessary functionality.

Comment: Ok I adjust the X/Y size from background and also I change you hack like this  = '\n'|| '    ' || name ||'    '|| '\n' because my text is centered. You very clever this is a Nice Hack !!!

Comment: You make me gain tons of hours !!!!

Comment: You can fine tune the hight using the line heigth. For horizontal is ok.

Comment: One of the greates hacks I ever read about, just wanted to ask the same question. Are there any new approaches to handle lable density in new QGIS versions?

Answer (score 4):

Here are a few indications that could help :

In the Layer properties select the Label Tab. In the Rendering subpage (rendu in french) on the right you can param a few things.

For example, limit the amount of Labels to be printed or merge connected line labels

The placement of labels can be customized under the Placement (Emplacement) subpage.

You can also look at [docs](http://docs.qgis.org/2.0/fr/docs/training_manual/vector_classification/label_tool.html)

Comment: THX, the amount of label will not fit to our need. Customizing placement either (we are not dealing with a small locality but with Europe map, so need a global solution). What do you mean by "merge connected line labels" ? The great option will be like "leave x mm space around label"....

Comment: "merge connected line labels" doesn't exist anymore in 2.8.1

Comment: @Mathieu To fit our focussed Q&A format can you consider using the **edit** button beneath your question to revise it with any additional information, please?  I recommend taking the [Tour], if you have not already.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add white space before and after the label to space them out. I'm using QGIS 3.22.

Use this label expression:

`concat('   ', "name", '   ')`

This turns this:

[image]

to this:

[image]